# Pythonのコードが意図した挙動になりません

Tags: python

初投稿ゆえ、拙い文章と汚いコードについてはご放念くださると幸いです
以下の2つのクラスがあります(Python 3.6.9)
二つのスタックを使って、キューを作成しようとしています

```python
class Stack:
  def __init__(self, data=[]):
    self.data = data

  def push(self, val):
    self.data.append(val)
  
  def pop(self):
    if self.is_empty():
      return None
    v = self.data.pop()
    return v
    
  def peek(self):
    return None if self.is_empty() else self.data[-1]

  def is_empty(self):
    return len(self.data)==0
```

```python
class TwoStacksAsQueue:
  def __init__(self, capacity):
    self.new_stack = Stack()
    self.old_stack = Stack()
    self.capacity = capacity

  def add(self, val):
    if self.is_full(self.new_stack):
      raise Exception("No more capacity")
    self.new_stack.push(val)

  def remove(self) -> Union[int, None]:
    if self.old_stack.is_empty():
      if self.new_stack.is_empty():
        return None
      while self.new_stack.is_empty():
        p = self.new_stack.pop()
        self.old_stack.push(p)
    v = self.old_stack.pop()
    return v

  def peek(self) -> Union[int, None]:
    if self.old_stack.is_empty():
      if self.new_stack.is_empty():
        return None
      while self.new_stack.is_empty():
        p = self.new_stack.pop()
        self.old_stack.push(p)
    v = self.old_stack.peek()
    return v
```

この状態で例えば以下のようなコードを実行すると、最後の`q.remove()`で返ってくる値は3であってほしいので対し、実際返ってくる値は5です。

```python
q = TwoStacksAsQueue()
q.add(3)
q.add(4)
q.add(5)
q.remove()
```

デバッグをしたところ、`TwoStacksAsQueue`クラスの`add`メソッドで`self.new_stack.data`にのみ値を入れているはずが、`self.new_stack.data`と`self.old_stack.data`両方に値が入っていました

つまりスタックの`self.data`が別のインスタンスのはずなのにシェアされているのでは、と思ったのですが、それはなぜでしょうか？

Comment: コンストラクタ `TwoStacksAsQueue.__init__()`  に `print(id(self.new_stack.data))` と `print(id(self.old_stack.data))` を追加してみると分かるかと思いますが、同じ id になっています(同じメモリ領域が割り当てられている)。`Stack.data` を明示的に指定すると異なるメモリ領域が割り当てられる様になります。`self.new_stack = Stack([])`, `self.old_stack = Stack([])` ですが、他にもちょっとした誤りがありますので、`3` ではなく `None` が表示されてしまいますけれども。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。インスタンスを明示的に指名しなければ別のインスタンスとしてみなされないのは、私にとって新しい発見でした。また、正しく動かすには`while self.new_stack.is_empty():`のところを`while not self.new_stack.is_empty():`ですね。重ねてありがとうございました。解決しました。

Comment: 参考までに挙げておきます。[Mutable Default Arguments](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments) **Python’s default arguments are evaluated once when the function is defined, not each time the function is called.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

関数またはメソッドの引数にデフォルトオブジェクトを指定する場合、関数またはメソッドの呼び出し毎に、関数定義時に評価されたデフォルトオブジェクトを引数に代入する動作となります。

```
class Stack:
  def __init__(self, data=[]):
    self.data = data
```

は

```
class Stack:
  def __init__(self, data=None):
    if data is None:
        data = []
    self.data = data
```

とすれば意図した動作になるでしょう。

なお、Stack クラスを実装するのであれば list を継承して

```
class Stack(list):
    def push(self, v):
        self.append(v)
    def peek(self):
        return None if self.is_empty() else self[-1]
    def is_empty(self):
        return not self
```

としてはいかがでしょう。

Comment: ありがとうございます、的確に答えてくださり助かりました。
listを継承することもできるのですね。